# How come I can redefine \maketitlehooka but not pass the same as an argument to \pretitle in the titling package?

Tags: macros, titling

I am attempting to change the font and size of the title through means of the titling package.

In the documentation, it is described that the `\maketitle` now looks something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
  \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka
  {\pretitle \title \posttitle}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\preauthor \author \postauthor}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\predate \date \postdate}
  \maketitlehookd
}
```

And that the `\pre` & `\post` macros can be used to change the typesetting of the title. Also the `\maketitlehookX` can be used to add stuff or change formatting. I've noticed that the `\pre` and  `\post` macros only seem to work when I explicitly create a group or an environment within which I do my work (be it changing formatting or adding some extra text to the title). But if I add the text or formatting as arguments to the `\pretitle` macro I get an error:

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{titlepage} on input line 9 ended by \end{center}.
```

However if I `\renewcommand\maketitlehooka` with the same text/formatting it works fine. I suppose the question is what is different between redefining a macro as described and passing the same code as an argument? or Why do I need to explicitly need to start a group within the `{...}` which already surrounds the `pre/post title`-group?

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{titling}    % taking control over the title format
%\renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\sffamily\bfseries} % Works
%\pretitle{\sffamily\bfseries} % Does not work
\pretitle{\begingroup\sffamily\bfseries} % This also works, kind of
\posttitle{\endgroup} % but needs this and will mess up some other formating
\title{The title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

It is worth noting that redefining `\maketitlehooka` requires only some small changes to make it look like I want while using `\begingroup\endgroup` will flush everything right and reset the font size. So `\begingroup\endgroup` might not be exactly what I'd want to use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the default definitions `\pretitle` and `\posttitle`. Their definitions at package load (from [`titling.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.dtx) are

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 2em}
```

So, updating `\pretitle` to

```
\pretitle{\sffamily\bfseries}
```

leaves an unpaired `\end{center}` in `\posttitle` which causes the problem. So, you either need to redefine *both*, or add your formatting as part of it. Here are some options:

- Appending content to `\@bspretitle` - the macro holding whatever is passed to `\pretitle`:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\@bspretitle{\sffamily\bfseries}
  \makeatother
  ```
- Redefining `\pretitle` entirely but include the original

  ```
  \pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\sffamily\bfseries}
  ```
- Updating *both* `\pretitle` and `\posttitle` if you want to remove the `center` environment and `\LARGE` formatting:

  ```
  \pretitle{\sffamily\bfseries}
  \posttitle{}
  ```

  There is no need for a group here, since the group is already established in the definition of `\maketitle`.
- Updating `\maketitlehooka` to insert the content in the appropriate location:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}[1]{{%
    \@bspretitle
    \sffamily\bfseries
    \@title
    \@bsposttitle
  }}
  \makeatother
  ```

  Note the additional group to limit the scope of the formatting. This is because we've redefined `\maketitlehooka` to take an argument. This argument removes the original definition scope.